# How to find a non-existing value from another table in mysql using ONE single QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to find number of types of produce of each farmer, names of farmer and the total number of produces but I am getting stuck in the part trying to display farmers who do not produce anything in the supplies and then in another query I want to extend it to display farmers with highest produces but without using the limit function.

```
    -- Table Farmer
create table Farmer(
    FarmerID char(3),
    FarmerName varchar(40),
    FarmName varchar(40),
    FarmLocation varchar(40),
    primary key(FarmerID));


-- Table ProduceType
create table ProduceType(
    ProdTypeID char(3),
    ProdTypeName varchar(20),
    primary key(ProdTypeID));

-- Table Produce
create table Produce(
    ProduceID char(3),
    ProduceName varchar(20),
    ProdTypeID char(3),
    primary key(ProduceID),
    foreign key(ProdTypeID) references ProduceType(ProdTypeID));
-- Table Supplies
create table Supplies(
    ProduceID char(3),
    FarmerID char(3),
    Weight decimal(5,2),
    Metric varchar(10),
    PricePerWeight decimal(5,2),
    primary key(ProduceID,FarmerID),
    foreign key(ProduceID) references Produce(ProduceID),
    foreign key(FarmerID) references Farmer(FarmerID));
```

My current attempt which is not working

```
    select count(p.prodtypeid) as 'number of types of produce', farmername, count(p.produceid) as 'total number of produces'
from farmer f, supplies s, producetype pt, produce p
where f.farmerid = s.farmerid
and p.prodtypeid = pt.prodtypeid
and s.produceid = p.produceid
or not exists ( select ff.farmerid
                from farmer ff, supplies ss where ff.farmerid = ss.farmerid)
group by farmername;
```

The output should be

```
Farmername | number of produce | number of producetye
Daniel          | 2                 | 2
Alex           |2                  |2
Lewis          | 1                  |1
Michale         | 0                 | 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProdTypeID) AS `number of types of produce`, 
       f.FarmerName, 
       COUNT(p.ProduceID) AS `total number of produces`
FROM Farmer f
JOIN Supplies s USING (FarmerID)
JOIN Produce p USING (ProduceID)
GROUP BY FarmerName;
```

This query gives "number of types of produce of each farmer, names of farmer and the total number of produces".

```
SELECT FarmerName
FROM Farmer
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM Supplies
                   WHERE Farmer.FarmerID = Supplies.FarmerID  );
```

This query gives "farmers who do not produce anything in the supplies".

The restriction - the lost relations (the rows in `Supplies` where `FarmerId` has definite value but `ProduceID` is NULL) not exists. For to guarantee this define both mentioned columns as NOT NULL in table structure.

---

> The output should be ..

```sql
SELECT f.FarmerName, 
       COALESCE(COUNT(p.ProduceID), 0) AS `total number of produces`,
       COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProdTypeID), 0) AS `number of types of produce`
FROM Farmer f
LEFT JOIN Supplies s USING (FarmerID)
LEFT JOIN Produce p USING (ProduceID)
GROUP BY FarmerName;
```

Left joining does not allow to reject the farmer rows which has no according rows in another tables. COALESCE function replaces NULLs obtained for such rows with zero value.

Comment: It has to be done in a single query. Not two separate queries that is my problem

Comment: @AnimRahman *It has to be done in a single query.* Please edit the question and add desired output sample - I cannot imagine how such output must look like.

Comment: Please check it now

Comment: @AnimRahman In this case you does not need in obtaining "farmers who do not produce anything in the supplies". I'll add a query shortly.